# OWL Carousel dots not working properly for 1.1 slide for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Trying to fix nav dots for 1.1 slides for owl carousel2. The thumbnail needs to be shows as 1.1 per slide and dots should cover for each slide.

```
`     $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false,
        margin: 24,
        loop: false,
        responsiveClass: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 7000,
        smartSpeed: 200,
        navText : ['<img  src="../../../../images/images/arrow-left-slider.svg" width="24px" height="24px" >','<img  src="../../../../images/images/arrow-right-slider.svg" width="24px" height="24px" >'],
        nav: true,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1.1,
            dots: true
          },

          1280: {
              items: 4,
              dots:false,
          },

        },
      });`
```